# ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(20,27): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular

> **` ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(20,27): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>         Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.**

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        declare const fileSelected: any;

         @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
      })
      export class AppComponent {

     binaryStr :any;
     inputObj :any;
      fileSelected(inputObj){

        var fileObj = this.inputObj.files[0];
        var webworkerReader = new FileReader();

        webworkerReader.onload = function(){
       var binaryStr = webworkerReader.result;
       var base64Str = btoa(binaryStr);

        webworkerReader.readAsBinaryString(fileObj);
       };
      }
       onclick(){
       fileSelected(this.inputObj);

      }
   }
```

Why am I getting this error? How to solve it?

Comment: Please provide your code where you are getting this error!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the angular variable here instead of creating a var variable

**Old**

```
 var binaryStr = webworkerReader.result;
```

**New**

```
this.binaryStr = webworkerReader.result;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `FileReader.result`.

For example,

```
const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = (event: Event) => {
   event.target.result; // This is invalid
   fileReader.result; // This is valid
};
```

Change : `var webworkerReader : FileReader = new FileReader();`